# Android MediaController intercepts all other touch events

Tags: android, touch-event, mediacontroller

The top half of my app has a `VideoView` with a `MediaController` under it. The bottom half is an image with some buttons. While the `MediaController` is visible, the buttons below are not clickable. It's like while the `MediaController` is visible, it intercepts all other touch events, even if they are not within the bounds of the `MediaController`.

Any idea around that?

Comment: Could you give us an idea of what your application's layout XML looks like?

Comment: I didn't start this bounty btw. I'd have to dig through my projects to find the XML

Comment: There's a strongly similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022117/add-view-on-top-of-mediacontroller but since no answer has been accepted there, flagging this one duplicate doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>You can check out [my answer on overriding `dispatchTouchEvent()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12063783/375929) to pass clicks through `MediaController` to an underlying `Button`, but I'm guessing there's something wrong with the way you use MediaController. Can you post your layout?</strike>

**UPD:**
Actually, strike that. I've just taken a look at [`MediaController`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/MediaController.java#MediaController.initFloatingWindow%28%29) code and it turns out it creates a new `Window` for itself. That's why your clicks don't get dispatched — they're dispatched to another window. Also, as far as I can tell from the [constructor code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/MediaController.java#MediaController.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.util.AttributeSet%29), if you inflate the MediaController via xml (i.e. use it in a layout file and then just find it by id from you code) — it won't create the extra `Window`. That's weird, but I'm sure they had reasons for that.

So, the solution is to either try to use MediaController in a layout file or go with [CommonsWare's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449001/375929). Please, let me know how it goes in case you give the xml thing a try.

Comment: [Media controller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) "The way to use this class is to instantiate it programatically ". Using it in a layout seems to cause a crash with a null pointer exception

Comment: @Casebash _Functions like show() and hide() have no effect when MediaController is created in an xml layout_ – so that scenario is also a valid one. Also, they would have not made the constructor for xml in the first place. At what point does the NPE occur?

Comment: It was crashing during `setAnchorView`. I removed it, but now it doesn't display

Comment: same problem here Casebash - did you find a solution?

Comment: @IvanBartsov Thanx for pointing this out... I cannot even believe 'MediaController' is so badly designed...

Comment: @smitalm Ah, the awesome feeling of still receiving thanks half a year later... Glad I could help, make sure to upvote the answer ;)

Answer (score 8):

> Any idea around that?

Do not use `MediaController`. Create your own controller UI that you pop up and display as needed. While [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry) may no longer completely work, as I have not touched in three years, it demonstrates having your own controller panel that pops up on a touch and then goes away.

Comment: Is that a recommendation to avoid using `MediaController` in general, or just in situations where one needs the UI beneath it to continue functioning?

Comment: @Spinner: Well, it definitely needs to be avoided if you want clicks on the rest of the UI to work. Beyond that, last I checked, `MediaController` was kinda lame from a UI and functionality standpoint, anyway, so you're probably better off with something else. That being said, if you don't mind `MediaController` being effectively modal, and you want to use it, go right ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Could you supply your VideoView instantiation code and the code you use to switch out the MediaPlayers?

In any case, I doubt this will work well because the VideoView instantiates its own MediaPlayer and uses it to play media. (see [VideoView.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/VideoView.java))

You would probably need to switch out the VideoView itself, or build a replacement for the VideoView using your own subclass of SurfaceView.

Answer (score 0):

I have face same issue, my UI element block due to media player, After spend 5 hours I got solution

I just replace mediaPlayer.prepare() to mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();