# ActionBar touch events being overriden by MediaController

Tags: android, window, android-videoview, touch-event, mediacontroller

I'm building an app with custom `MediaController` and `VideoView` (both using 99% of the original android code) to display my videos. When the activity is in landscape i set the actionbar (using actionbarsherlock 4.2.0) to overlay the `VideoView` just like in the youtube app.

When you click the video view the mediacontroller alternates between visible and invisible, but when it's visible you can use the buttons to control the video, but if i touch on a actionbar item it doesn't work and just hides the mediacontroller because he intercepted the touch event.

I've looked at the code of the `MediaController` and realized that he was creating a window that was filling the entire screen. So i fixed that and set the window to start exactly below the action bar but my touch calls are still being intercepted even with the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` set on the window so it doesn't block touch events outside (because the action bar is theoretically outside of the MediaController's window).

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Worst case scenario i would have to use one of the two solutions from like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909603/android-mediacontroller-intercepts-all-other-touch-events): Remove the window and use layout inflate or don't use MediaController at all